# How to fix 'Duplicate files copied in APK' error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

My android app is a simple login/registration app.

The error I am getting while running the code is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
>
> File1: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\App\app\libs\apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\App\app\libs\http-core-4.1.jar

File 1 and File 2 are the libraries that I included in the libs folder.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.admin.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.admin.app"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        } }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' }
}
```

**EDIT-1:**

I overwrote the library files and ran the code and got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ProtocolException.class

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Click on Build > Clean Project > Rebuild Project..

Comment: Same error is occuring.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ProtocolException.class

Comment: Do not manually include jar files that also exist in the maven repository. This will break the dependency management. Replace each jar file with the one from https://mvnrepository.com and define it like the multidex library.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log, your final APK contains duplicate files which usually means your 2 dependencies are adding 2 same files in the final APK to cause this issue.

You can exclude a particular file in final APK by specifying it in your `build.gradle` file by adding the following:

```
android {
     packagingOptions {
         exclude '...'
     }
 }
```

Add this into your `build.gradle` and don't forget to replace the "..." with the name (it requires absolute path) of the duplicate file.

PS: I recommend using [Retrofit library](https://github.com/square/retrofit/) to performing networking in Android apps